# How to write a generic function that updates fields of a Record

Tags: field, record, elm

Consider

```
type alias Rec = { a: Int, b: Int, c:Int }
updateRec r aVal            = { r|a = aVal } 
updateRec2 r aVal bVal      = { r|a = aVal, b= bVal } 
updateRec3 r aVal bVal cVal = ...
```

How to generalize `updateRec` and `updateRec2`... into one function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a better way of doing the same thing:

```
updateA : Int -> Rec -> Rec
updateA x rec = { rec | a = x }

-- Similarly for b, c
```

Now you can do the following, supposing you already have a value `rec : Rec` you want to update:

```
myUpdatedRec : Rec
myUpdatedRec =
  rec 
  |> updateA 7
  |> updateB 19
```

You can now update an arbitrary number of fields by stringing together `|> updateX ...`.

Comment: I like this much better.

Answer (score 2):

You want to write a function that has a variable number of differently-typed parameters. That's common in dynamically typed languages (Javascript, Python, Ruby) but usually not allowed in typed languages. Elm doesn't allow it.

You can emulate a variable number of differently-typed parameterswith the `Maybe` type, understanding `Nothing` as "missing argument":

```
updateRec : Rec -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Rec
updateRec r a b c = 
  { r
  | a = a |> Maybe.withDefault r.a
  , b = b |> Maybe.withDefault r.b
  , c = c |> Maybe.withDefault r.c
  }
```

If the record fields are all of the same type (here `Int`), you could accept a `List Int` instead:

```
updateRec : Rec -> List Int -> Rec 
updateRec r fields = 
  case fields of 
    [a] -> { r | a = a }
    [a,b] -> { r | a = a, b = b }
    [a,b,c] -> { r | a = a, b = b, c = c }
    _ -> r
```

I don't like this solution because you it'll fail silently if you accidentally supply a list with 0 or 4+ elements. If this function is helpful to you anyway, perhaps it would be better to use `List Int` instead of `Rec` in the first place.

Comment: Apparently, even if JS, you will need additional code as per this article - http://javascript.crockford.com/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/ . Your first version will work for me ,thanks.

Comment: I'm getting an error in the eml-repl as follows: 

   The 2nd argument to function `updateRec` is causing a mismatch.

      updateRec r 3 
                 ^
      Function `updateRec` is expecting the 2nd argument to be:

      `Maybe number`

      But it is:

      `number`

Comment: Sounds as if you're trying to do a call `updateRec r 3 ...` but you need to call it `updateRec r (Just 3)`.

Comment: Got it! But then, `updateRec (Just 1) (Just 2) (Just 3)` ...it can get long winded...makes me want to agree with @Chad that this is probably not as intuitive as the record `update` syntax, but useful to know that it _is_ possible.

Comment: Agree. Your comment made me think of a different answer which I gave below.

Answer (score 1):

Elm's record update syntax seems to be exactly what you are looking for. You "pass in" the record that you want updated, `r` below, and you can return a record with whatever fields you want changed without having to specify every field:

```elm
ex1 = { r|a = 1 }
ex2 = { r|b = 2, c = 3 }
```

You don't need to create a set of additional functions for updating only certain fields at certain times, because Elm's record update syntax *is* that generalized function.

Comment: Ok. Just for theoretical purposes, in the above code, `ex1` won't accept any parameters, right? Or, how would you invoke `ex1` and `ex2`?

Comment: Right. I would argue that you don't need to define any extra functions for general purpose updating. As for `ex1` and `ex2` above, those are for example purposes only and unnecessary depending on your situation. You _could_ do something like that inside a `let` statement to clean up your code. Otherwise, think of `{ r|a = 1 }` as a value unto itself that can be used wherever values are used.